# React native get SHA-1 certificate fingerprint in expo (windows)?

Tags: react-native, expo

I need to get my SHA-1 certificate fingerprint and I use expo I already saw other answers but they are use CLI or they use mac commands which is not my case. I also run `expo credentials:manager` but the output doesn't contain the thing I want. how can I get this? thanks in advance.